# Django Factory Boy Create vs create_batch

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests, factory-boy

I am learning django test and i found django factory boy library very helpfull for writing testcase but one thing i am not getting..

forexample my one of Factory name is `BlogFactory`

so i notice, most of the people use this like this: `BlogFactory.create()` and some people use it like this.. `BlogFactory.create_batch()` I am not getting difference between it..

What is different between `create` and `create_batch` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- [`create()`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.create) is for mocking a single instance of a class.
- [`create_batch(size, ...)`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.create_batch) is for mocking multiple instances.

The `create_batch` method of a factory cannot be called without parameters as `create()`, since `size` is required by design (see the docs link above).